# Say whether $V = \mathcal{P}_{3}(\mathbb{R})$ is isomorphic to $W = M_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{R})$ and if it is give an isomorphism.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-space-isomorphism

Since the dimensions are same I am assuming an isomorphism exists. I know I would have to check whether it is one-to-one and onto, but how to I give an isomorphism. I am confused on what that means. Thank you in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by P3(R)?

Comment: @MichaelCohen I assume all plynomials of degree less than or 3. In such case, they are isomorphic as vector spaces over the real numbers.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

Since they have the same dimension, they are isomorphic.

In order to conclude so, we shall proceed as follows.

To begin with, consider the following ordered basis for $V$:
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{B}_{V} = \{v_{1},v_{2},v_{3},v_{4}\} = \{1,x,x^{2},x^{3}\}
\end{align*}
Similarly, consider the following ordered basis for $W$:
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{B}_{W} = \{w_{1},w_{2},w_{3},w_{4}\} = \left\{
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1\\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0\\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\right\}
\end{align*}

Then there exists (and it is unique!) the linear transformation $T:V\to W$ defined by $T(v_{i}) = w_{i}$.

Can you prove that $T$ is injective in order to conclude that $T$ is an isomorphism based on the rank-nullity theorem?

Comment: I understand that the rank would be 4 and the nullity hence, 0 so it's one-to-one. I have another question where W-F^3 what would that basis look like?